# react app throwing error with node upgraded to 18 and webpack resolve extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, webpack, yarnpkg-v3

We're in the process of upgrading our React project's Node version from 10 to 18. However, after the upgrade, we are encountering issues with our webpack configuration, specifically with the resolve extensions.

Here is the relevant part of our webpack configuration:

```
  modules: ['packages', 'verticals', 'node_modules', 'folder1'],
  extensions: [
    isServer ? '.server.tsx' : '.client.tsx',
    isServer ? '.server.jsx' : '.client.jsx',
    isServer ? '.server.ts' : '.client.ts',
    isServer ? '.server.js' : '.client.js',
    '.web.tsx',
    '.web.jsx',
    '.web.ts',
    '.web.js',
    '.tsx',
    '.jsx',
    '.ts',
    '.js',
    '.json',
  ],
}
```

Since upgrading, we are encountering the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Documents/Project/node_modules/logger/src/logger'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry.
```

The issue seems to be related to the different sources for the logger file based on whether it's used on the client or server (server.tsx and client.tsx files).

For context, here are the dependencies listed in our package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.18.9",
  "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
  "array-flat-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
  "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
  "browserslist-useragent-regexp": "^3.0.2",
  "husky": "^4.2.3",
  "jest": "^26.6.3",
  "jest-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
  "lerna": "^4.0.0",
  "lint-staged": "^10.0.8",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
  "typesafe-actions": "^5.1.0",
  "typescript": "4.5.5",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.7.0",
  "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.5.4"
}
```

We would appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this webpack issue after upgrading to Node 18. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to remove your node_modules and re-install again ?

Comment: i've gone through a similar process with a vue app going from node 8 to node 18. to me this looks like one of the dependencies uses the logger sub-dependency. i'd start by looking what uses this dependency and see if there have been any changes in the APIs there, updating to the last compatible version. for my process, i was going up in steps based on webpack's versions since the bundler was the cornerstone for the rest of the dependencies. update from wb 3 to 4. fix the deps and change the implementation. rinse & repeat with another version bump

Comment: If you are simply updating node versions without updating any dependencies it might be pretty painful. Not enough info to really help you debug this. After 3 months of effort you might want to consider a contractor.

Comment: @cantdocpp, yes we did that.

Comment: @liminor, we use lerna packages and files. So we have two files, logger.client.tsx and logger.server.tsx. one for being executable at server and one at client. So when we imported the file it was like '/logger' and left this work with web pack to choose server or client file as you can see our web pack config. This is still working fine till node 14 but it now breaks.

Comment: @morganney, no we are not simply updating dependencies. We are updating whatever the dependency is there and we know. Is there any way I can help here to debug this issue better. Kindly let me know

Comment: @AbhishekSharma there’s a lot more you can share. Is that the only error? What does the file look like causing the error? Do you build to cjs or esm? How are you running the build? Webpack 4 or 5? Etc etc. Are you able to share a link to your project? Being able to reproduce this is important otherwise I’m just throwing darts in the dark.